# Get key by value in complex dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm wondering how I can return the key of a dictionary, based on whether it contains a certain value.  As shown below:

```
dic = {1: [(3,3)], 2: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (4, 3)]}

def get_key(pos):

    for key, value in dic.items():
        if value == pos:
           return key
```

As you can see, the function takes a single argument and checks if it is in the dictionary.  If so, it should return the corresponding key.

I've been searching through other StackOverflow questions, similar to mine, however, the solutions don't seem to work.

Comment: what is problem in above code

Answer (score 1):

The following code would work:

```
def get_key(pos):
    dic = {1: [(3,3)], 2: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (4, 3)]}
    for (key, value) in dic.items():
        if pos in value:
            return key
```

> pos = (1,2)
>
> get_key(pos)
>
> Output: 2

Value is returned as list and pos is a single tuple. So you should use **IN** to check if the pos is in the set of tuples returned as list.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass second argument and it works.

```
dic = {1: [(3,3)], 2: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (4, 3)]}

def get_key(pos, dic):

    for key, value in dic.items():
        if value == pos:
           return key

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_key([(3,3)], dic)
```

Below is the output

```
1
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: I upvoted you. Don't see why this got downvoted

Comment: This can't be the problem, even if it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning to search for a tuple in the dictionary?

```
dic = {1: [(3,3)], 2: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (4, 3)]}
def get_key(pos):
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if pos in value:
           return key

get_key((2,3)) // output 2
get_key((3,3)) // output 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using lambda and filter in single line .Hope this will help you

```
dic = {1: [(3,3)], 2: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (4, 3)]}

pos = (2,3)

get_key = filter(lambda x: pos in dic[x], dic)
print get_key[0]
```

You can read lambda details [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function)

Comment: Worth mentioning that generally "Pythonic" and "lambda/filter" don't go together well.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks...I had change my comment

Comment: `get_key = [k for k in dic if pos in dic[x]]` is the usual way that's written in Python. Though I love filter/map/reduce in other languages, Python doesn't use them much